# How can I change fonts and adjust their size in elementary OS

Tags: release-freya, fonts

Can I change the Freya font to my desired one.

What's the easiest way to change my fonts?

If I get google web-fonts or some professionally simple fonts.I am really happy to use it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can change system fonts using Elementary Tweaks:
https://launchpad.net/elementary-tweaks.
[image]

Comment: Where can i get this font options  . There is no option in mine.

Comment: You have to install Elementary Tweaks. After that: System Settings -> Tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

Install `gnome-tweak-tool` from software center. There you can change fonts.

[image: Imgur]

Comment: hey why downvote? please let me know :)

Comment: i didnt down vote it.

Answer (score 0):

Install `font-manager` from software center, there you can change fonts:

[image: Imgur]

From manage fonts option you can install fonts as well.